# Averiguar número de elementos en un array de LUA

Tags: c++, array, lua

¿Cómo puedo averiguar el número de elementos que contiene un array en un fichero LUA? me gustaría poder volcarlo a un entero desde C++.

```
-- Fichero LUA
array_of_integers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

---

```
// Fichero C++
int num_elements = ... // <--- esto es lo que necesito
std::cout << num_elements << std::endl; // 5
```

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: ¿Qué librería de LUA estás usando en C++?

Comment: 5.3.3. @Trauma ha dado con una solución: size_t lua_objlen (lua_State *L, int index) de la 5.1 y he buscado el análogo a mi versión y he encontrado lua_Integer luaL_len(lua_State *L, int idx).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Del manual de Lua 5.1:

> size_t lua_objlen (lua_State *L, int index);
>
> Returns the "length" of the value at the given acceptable index: for strings, this is the string length; for tables, this is the result of the length operator ('#'); for userdata, this is the size of the block of memory allocated for the userdata; for other values, it is 0.

Devuelve la 'longitud' de un valor colocado en la pila, en el índice *aceptable* **index**.

- Para cadenas de texto, es la longitud de la cadena.
- **Para tablas, es el resultado del operador #**.
- Para *userdata*, es el tamaño del bloque de memória usado.
- Para otros tipos, es 0.

El valor es devuelto directamente al código llamante, **sin** colocarlo en la pila de Lua.

Comment: Correcto, funciona. Finalmente lo he implementado con el método lua_Integer luaL_len(lua_State *L, int idx) del manual de Lua 5.3 que es básicamente lo mismo. Muchas gracias @Trauma

Comment: Te respondí para la versión 5.1 porque es la que estoy empezando a usar yo ahora mismo (por LuaJIT). Si tienes libertad para escoger la versión, te recomiendo que la uses. Las ganancias de velocidad de LuaJIT son impresionantes, pero solo soporta la versión 5.1 de lua, con ciertas extensiones y añadidos.

Comment: Gracias por la info @Trauma voy a testear la 5.1 a ver que tal.